# Does Italian language have letters for foreign sounds?

Tags: sound, letters, pronunciation

Some sounds don't exist in Italian, such as the Arabic sounds *dad* (*ض*), *qaf* (*ق*), or *ain* (*ع*).

Are there letters or syllables for these sounds?

Answer (score 5):

As other languages using the Latin alphabet, Italian doesn't have letters for foreign sounds; the word is written using Latin characters in a conventional way.

Comment: Sometimes latin sounds can't be used to make the same word, since they are quite specific and limited sounds. I guess in that case, if the actual sound is important, a system like [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) may be used?

Comment: In automatic rendering of Arabic names, I have sometimes seen "3". I do not know which sound that corresponds to though.